# Do Indian nationals require a transit visa at Vienna travelling from Ukraine to India?

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, vienna

One of my friends is studying in Ukraine, now he wants to travel to India for vacation via Vienna. Does he require a transit visa?

Answer (score 1):

No, he does not need a visa, provided he can stay in the international area of the airport (which means in particular that his luggage must be checked through to his final destination).

See also [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area) for a full explanation of the rules. The most important thing is that India is not on the list of countries whose citizens require an airport transit visa in the Schengen area. A visa is only required to transit through Germany, France, Spain and the Czech Republic.

Answer (score -1):

No, an Indian Citizen also does not need a Transit Visa if they are traveling from USA towards their home or vice versa via Germany. I have traveled via Frankfurt both ways, and it did not require me to have any Schengen or Transit Visa.

Comment: The question is about **Ukraine**, not the **United States**.